# The graph section of Cypher response, remains blank

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I noticed for some queries the response populates the "graph" section as follows

---

```
        }
      ],
      "graph": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": "68",
            "labels": [
              "ROOM"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "id": 15,
              "name": "Sun and Snow",
```

---

but for other queries, this "graph" section is not returning with nodes/relationships and associated labels/properties even though the "data" section returns valid output

Does it convey anything about the quality of the cypher query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you return from your query.  If you return nodes and relationships, you'll get a graph.  If you return scalars such as n.name or r.weight, you don't get a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the HTTP requests from the web UI or requests that you are making yourself?

The `graph` key is controlled via the `resultDataContents` option when making a request.  You can see the documentation for that here:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format

You can request multiple formats for the result (`"row"` and `"REST"` are other examples)

Comment: Hi @Brian. I am just running the HTTP queries from the Web UI. With different queries was expecting a uniform type response [either all with "graph" section populated or none] but encountered that anomaly

Comment: Interesting, so you're watching the request from the Web UI?  Can you see if the browser is making different requests at different times depending on context?